# apt-get update Unable to connect to and fetch error

Tags: server, apt, updates, vps

I can't seem to be capable of updating or install the packages on my uBuntu 14.04 LTS Minimal VPS server.

Every time i run `apt-get update` i get the following long message:

```
root@cryptogates:~# apt-get update
Ign http://nginx.org trusty InRelease
Hit http://nginx.org trusty Release.gpg
Hit http://nginx.org trusty Release
Hit http://nginx.org trusty/nginx amd64 Packages
Hit http://nginx.org trusty/nginx i386 Packages
Ign http://nginx.org trusty/nginx Translation-en
Hit http://apt.vestacp.com trusty InRelease
Hit http://apt.vestacp.com trusty/vesta amd64 Packages
Hit http://apt.vestacp.com trusty/vesta i386 Packages
Ign http://apt.vestacp.com trusty/vesta Translation-en
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to extras.ubuntu.com:http:
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease
Ign http://download.webmin.com sarge InRelease
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release
Err http://download.webmin.com sarge Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to download.webmin.com:http:
Ign http://download.webmin.com sarge Release

W: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to ca.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to ca.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to ca.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to ca.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/main/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to ca.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to ca.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/restricted/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to ca.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to ca.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

At first the server was pushing IPV6 instead of IPv4, keeping the update % at 0, i fixed it by:

```
If you want to make the setting persistent just create /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99force-ipv4 and put Acquire::ForceIPv4 "true"; in it.
```

But now i reach 100% yet it still fails.